# Information hiding with EF generated entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, entity-framework-5

Can I make EF to generate entity classes with private property setters?

Eg. I want something like

```
public class MyTable
{
    public Guid Id {get; private set;}
    //... And so on and so forth, basically the class should hide the setters
}
```

Comment: Look in the property window of a selected property on your .edmx under code generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using tt templates to generate POCO entities, by modifying the tt file it is possible.

On the otherhand, since private variables will not be serialized during WCF communication, you will face with problems if you are using any service - client architecture and exchanging generated entities.

Comment: No, t4 template does this already. Just set the code generated setter to private for the property in .edmx model property window.

Comment: @bmewsing I need to check that.

Comment: Yeah I will have seperate DTOs and a mapper. Thanks. Btw how does the context keep track of which values were changed if I made them private?

Comment: POCO works by generating proxy dynamically, hence the virtual properties. If you make the fields private than how would the proxy override the setters?